# Django+Gunicorn incorrect logs timestamp

Tags: django, logging, timezone, timestamp, utc

In my Django settings and on my machine I have utc+3 configured time so the expectations were to get all logs in utc+3, but turned out, that actually  they are pretty messy:

```
[2017-08-08 10:29:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-08-08 10:29:22 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2017-08-08 10:29:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000
[2017-08-08 10:29:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-08-08 10:29:22 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2017-08-08 10:29:23 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 1 worker
[2017-08-08 13:29:26 +0300] [7] [INFO] [dashboard.views:9] Displaying menu
```

Settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_TZ = True
```

Maybe you can provide some hints/information how to configure or debug it?

For a moment I thought that this is a gunicorn's problem, but it uses Django settings soo I have no idea what's wrong :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gunicorn logging time do not relay on Django timezone, but in the local machine one, so to get the right timezone you should configure your local machine and how to do it depends in what OS is running on it.

For Debian/Ubuntu:

> 1. sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
> 2. Follow the directions in the terminal.
> 3. The timezone info is saved in /etc/timezone - which can be edited or used below

If you are using CentOS you can check it in [this article](https://chrisjean.com/change-timezone-in-centos/).

For other options, check it in Google.

Hope that it helps.

Comment: machine time zone is utc+3 too...
**$sudo systemsetup -gettimezone: $Time Zone: Europe/Moscow**

Answer (score 2):

So, the timestamps were correct, but different because of my company proxy settings. Also it turned out that is best way to handle different time zones is just use utc everywhere except presentation to user.